# REGEX expression to add some amount of whitespaces to the word

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, code-snippets

I`m trying to write a snip pet for Sublime Text 2.
The idea is that the user types a string which will be passed to the called snippet as an argument $TM_CURRENT_WORD. I need to write a regex expression which will fill the given word with spaces up to 16 characters in total.

E.g.
user input: `SOMEWORD` - 8 ch.
code in the snippet: `${$TM_CURRENT_WORD/"some regex magic"/"something more"}`
output: `SOMEWORDssssssss` (here s means whitespace)

or:
user input: `WORD` - 4 ch.
output shoud be: `WORDssssssssssss` - input word + 12 whitespaces.

In general, input could be from 1 up to 16 characters, but the output should be exactly 16 characters. If 16 character`s word will be given? no whitespaces should be added.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Why would you think a regex is needed (or even appropriate) here?

Comment: @Ken is right - use app code to add 16 - length spaces

Comment: @RohitJain I don`t have any solution now, because I`m not sure if it basically possible. My knowledge of regex is quite low, I`m just starting learning regex. @KenWhite Sublime uses the PERL syntax of regex to operate with strings in snippets, that`s why I need a regex. @Bohemian the app code for which i`m writting snippet doesn`t allow to much string editting options.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you could just write a small plugin that does exactly what you want.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class AddPaddingCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        selections = self.view.sel()
        for s in selections:
            word = self.view.substr(s)
            padded_word = '{0: <16}'.format(word)
            self.view.replace(edit, s, padded_word)
```